# QR Code BitMap Creation Out of Memory from ZXing Library in Android

Tags: java, android, bitmap, out-of-memory, zxing

I am trying to generate QR Codes with the ZXing Library, which generates a BitMatrix and subsequently a BitMap using the following code:

```
    BitMatrix result;
    try {
        result = new MultiFormatWriter().encode(encodeString, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, WIDTH, WIDTH, null);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
        // Unsupported format
        return null;
    }
    int w = result.getWidth();
    int h = result.getHeight();
    int[] pixels = new int[w * h];
    for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
        int offset = y * w;
        for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
            pixels[offset + x] = result.get(x, y) ? foregroundColor : backgroundColor;
        }
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);
```

After running this function exactly 100 times (tested several times, always on the 100th run), the app crashes due to a memory error:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 2560012 byte
>   allocation with 1053776 free bytes and 1029KB until OOM
>                                                                                 at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:879)
>                                                                                 at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:856)
>                                                                                 at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:823)

Adding `android:largeHeap="true"` simply prolongs this crash.

Is there a way to solve this out of memory error?

Comment: Not surprised to see no one addressed it. It's kind of tricky.

To give more inputs on this, this doesn't happen generally with a normal density screen. It happens with high resolution(FHD or QHD) screens like Samsung S8 screen with optional FHD or QHD res.